# Unable to get accurate historical data from Tradingview Pinescript v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I struggle to get the correct historical data in Tradinview using Pinescript version 5.

Follow a simple function that returns the current EPS growth comparing it to the previous year:

```
// EPS Last Year Quarter % Growth
getEpsYrQtGrowth() => 
    var float epsGrowthAbove = input.float(defval = 0.25, title = "EPS(YQ) ▲ - ▼ (%)", minval = -100, step = 0.01, inline="EPS Last Year Quarter % Growth", group = "Fundamental")
    var float epsGrowthBelow = input.float(defval = 0.2, title = "-", minval = 0, step = 0.01, inline="EPS Last Year Quarter % Growth", group = "Fundamental")

    float currEps = request.earnings(ticker = syminfo.tickerid, field = earnings.actual, ignore_invalid_symbol = true, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
    float prevEps = request.security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = "3M", expression = currEps[3], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
    
    float epsGrowth = prevEps == 0 ? 1 : nz(currEps / prevEps - 1)
    color epsGrowthColor = (epsGrowth >= epsGrowthAbove) ? colorIndAbove : (epsGrowth <= epsGrowthBelow) ? colorIndBelow : colorIndNeutral

    fundamentalObject.new(value = epsGrowth, color = epsGrowthColor)
```

The problem is: every time the user changes the timeframe into the current chart, it will affect and throw off the `prevEps` timeframe and expression, giving a different EPS result. That even happens sometimes, changing the ticker itself.

I'm trying in all ways possible update the `timeframe = "3M", expression = currEps[1]` and test it with many tickers to see if I can get right data.

How can anyone get accurate EPS historical data without it be changed by current chart timeframe or ticker?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
float currEpsActual = request.earnings(ticker = syminfo.tickerid, field = earnings.actual, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
float currEpsStandard = request.earnings(ticker = syminfo.tickerid, field = earnings.standardized, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
float currEpsEstimate = request.earnings(ticker = syminfo.tickerid, field = earnings.estimate, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

bool isEpsEvent = ta.barssince(currEpsActual != currEpsActual[1] or currEpsStandard != currEpsStandard[1] or currEpsEstimate != currEpsEstimate[1]) == 0 ? true : false

float currEps = currEpsActual
float currEps2 = ta.valuewhen(isEpsEvent, currEps, 1)
float currEps3 = ta.valuewhen(isEpsEvent, currEps, 2)
float prevEps = ta.valuewhen(isEpsEvent, currEps, 4)
float prevEps2 = ta.valuewhen(isEpsEvent, currEps, 5)
float prevEps3 = ta.valuewhen(isEpsEvent, currEps, 6)
```